# Figuring out my sqlite version

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, conda

I wanted to check which version of sqlite I had, which has become way more confusing than I expected. To start fresh, I created a new conda environment with:

```
conda create --name my_env_name python=3.6 sqlite hdf5 pandas
```

The shell message said it would install `sqlite: 3.13.0-1` in the new environment, along with a few other packages.

Then, after activating that new conda environment, I immediately ran `pip freeze`, but the list of packages I see does not include any entry for `sqlite`.

Finally, I just enter `python` from the terminal (in this conda env) to enter a system python in my shell. The opening message says python version 3.6.1, confirming I'm in that newly created environment. But then

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.version
```

outputs `'2.6.0'`

What's going on? Do I have sqlite3 version 3.13 installed or 2.6? If my sqlite3 version is 2.6, how do I get something newer? That would be pretty old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have installed the `sqlite: 3.13.0-1` version of sqlite database. If you want to check, run `sqlite3 --version`

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.version
```

Here you get version for DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite which is `2.6.0`

Comment: much obliged. SO tells me I need to wait 7 minutes to accept this, will do then.

Comment: @MaxPower I'm new to StackOverflow. When you wrote SO. I was thinking why your significant other told you to wait 7 minutes :-D.

Answer (score 11):

1. Import sqlite3 into your python script:

   ```
   import sqlite3
   ```
2. Add the following lines to your script:

   ```
   print "SQLite Version is:", sqlite3.sqlite_version
   print "DB-API Version is:", sqlite3.version
   ```
3. Running the script produced the following results for me (your results may differ):

   ```
   SQLite Version is: 3.11.0
   DB-API Version is: 2.6.0
   ```

This information is documented in The Python Standard Library, 
"Section 12.6.1. Module functions and constants"
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html